# Solution pattern for 2D stencil pattern

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, von-neumann

I need to find a slution pattern to parallelize the following computation across a 2D plate (`Tx,y` is the value of `T` at position `(x,y)` and `C` and `D` are constants:

`Tx,y = Tx,y + C(Tx+1,y + Tx-1,y - 2Tx,y) + D(Tx,y+1 + Tx,y-1 - 2Tx,y)`

Basically it can be illustrated by the 5-point 2D von neumann stencil pattern(the middle one below).

[image]

But I can't find how to start computing. All the points are dependent on its neighboring points, so from where to start the computation?

Comment: One very common approach to such problems is to define two `planes`, call them `a` and `b`.  `a` represents your grid in its initial state, `b` is empty but the same size.  In step 1 you calculate the updated cell values in `b` based on the values in `a`, then in step 2 you update `a` from the values in `b`.  And so forth.  This increases the space required but makes a lot of computations very much simpler, especially when it comes to parallelisation.

Comment: The first element calculation is erroneous then? (Since its dependent values are still not updated)